# Could not resolve com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2

Tags: korge

Here's my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.10"
    id("maven-publish")
}

group = "com.xenotactic.gamelogic"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

val kormaVersion = "2.2.2"
val korioVersion = "2.6.2"

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    js(BOTH) {
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma:$kormaVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-protobuf:1.3.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10")
                implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:$korioVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting
        val jsTest by getting
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}
```

Got an error when running the `publishToMavenLocal` gradle task.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':jsLegacyTestPackageJson'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':jsLegacyTestNpm'.
   > Could not resolve com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a library, preferably optimized for non-jvm, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler' with value 'legacy' but:
          - Variant 'commonMainMetadataElements' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'debugApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a runtime of a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosArm32ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosArm32MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'iosX64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'jsApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler' with value 'ir' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler' with value 'legacy'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'jsRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler' with value 'ir' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler' with value 'legacy'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'jvmRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a runtime of a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'linuxX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'macosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'macosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'macosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'macosX64MetadataElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-metadata' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'mingwX64ApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements-published' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio:2.6.2 declares a runtime of a library:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler (required 'legacy')

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Text to satisfy adding "details":

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Answer (score 1):

Solved in: https://github.com/korlibs/korge-next/issues/490

The solution:

replace:

`js(BOTH) {`

with

`js(IR) {`